# Android Management API - usbMassStorageEnabled deprecated

Tags: android-management-api

I open this stackoverflow because i don't understand the documentation of android management api : https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies

[image: AAM usb mass storage enabled description]

On this image, we saw a `usbMassStorageEnabled` is deprecated, but we don't know what to replace this value with.

Does anyone know what to replace it with ?

Furthermore, my need is to block the usb ports (devices) of my device, If anyone knows the exact field to put, I would be very grateful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this policy is already deprecated. You can either use the policy [usbFileTransferDisabled](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#:%7E:text=fully%20managed%20devices.-,usbFileTransferDisabled,-boolean)  which will disable file sharing via USB or [MountPhysicalMediaDisabled](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#:%7E:text=apps%20is%20disabled.-,mountPhysicalMediaDisabled,-boolean) which will disable mounting physical external media. Either can be used depending on your specific needs.